# Value function optimization problem

Tags: markov-process

How to show that V* (optimal value function), is the solution to the following optimization problem: $min_V~ \Sigma_s V(s) $ with the constraint: $ V \ge T^{*}V $
Where $T^{*}$ is the optimal Bellman operator

Thanks